# Software Requirements Reviews with MS Word - How do I get metrics in an automated way?

Tags: requirements, review

Let's say I have a requirements document in MS Word, and someone else reviews it an provides a list of issues found using the "Track Changes" feature.

Is there a way to extract "how many major/minor issues were found during the review?" using an automated script - for metrics purposes?

I see [CodeCollaborator](http://smartbear.com/codecollab.php) has some MS Word integration, but it doesn't seem to know how to look inside Word to extract the tracked changes data.  It just launches the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did once write a Word macro that extracts the comments to a separate document, you are welcome to try adapting this to your purposes, if you have trouble then reply here and I can give you a hand with making changes.

```
Public Sub PROCESS_COMMENTS()

Dim strReplaceText As String
Dim myPar As Paragraph
Dim strCurrentColumn As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Com As Comment

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '   set the input and output docs.
    Set inDoc = ActiveDocument
    '   check we have comments to process in the original document
    If inDoc.Comments.Count < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No comments in the document"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '   comments exist so create new document
    Set outDoc = Documents.Add
    Set outRange = outDoc.Content

    outDoc.Range.InsertAfter "List of Comments:"
    outDoc.Paragraphs(outDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Style = outDoc.Styles("Heading 1")
    outDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter


    '   cycle through comments, inserting them in the new document
    '   display the new document and refresh
    outDoc.Activate
    Application.ScreenRefresh

    For Each Com In inDoc.Comments
        outRange.InsertAfter "[" & Com.Author & " - " & Com.Initial & Com.Index & "] "
        outDoc.Paragraphs(outDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Font.Bold = True
        outDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        outRange.InsertAfter Com.Range.Text
        outDoc.Paragraphs(outDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Font.Bold = False

        Set myRange = Com.Scope


        outDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        outDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set outDoc = ActiveDocument

End Sub
```